# is there any way to cancel rxjs's concatMap's inner observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I'm using angular 2 to create a file upload queue with chunk upload support.

here is the basic idea, I have a `added` EventEmitter fires when a validated file selected, then in ngOnInit I listen to this `added` event and map to a bunch of uploads like this:

```
this.start
.concatMap(item => item.file.size > this.chunkSize ? this.uploadChunks(item) : this.upload(item),
    (outer: QueueFile, inner: Response) => ({item: outer, response: inner}))
.subscribe((x: any) => this.uploadSucceed(x.item, x.response),
    (x: any) => this.uploadFailed(x.item, x.resp));
```

and the `uploadChunks` function like this:

```
private uploadChunks(item: QueueFile) {
    return Observable.range(0, Math.ceil(item.file.size / this.chunkSize), Scheduler.queue)
        .map(x => [x * this.chunkSize, Math.min(item.file.size, (x + 1) * this.chunkSize)])
        .map(x => this.createChunkFormData(x[0], x[1], item))
        .concatMap(data => this.http.post(this.url, data));
}
```

and I want to provide a cancel upload of chunks, but in this design, it seems there is no way to stop the chunks upload.

If I record the subscription to the start event, and unsubscribe it, then the whole queue will stops uploading.

Is it anyway to stop the uploadChunks? or maybe my method is totally wrong, if that so, how can I do this with rxjs?

Comment: you can cancel by throwing some error.

Comment: create some error will cause the whole upload queue stops :(

Comment: got it, my upload queue is stored in a array, when abort, just delete that queue item, then in `concatMap` of `uploadChunks` function, check for the item existance in queue array, if exists, return the `http.post` otherwise return a `Observable.empty()`, then the chunks upload will stop and continue to next queue item.