# Cancel all items in a queue with RxJS

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a function called `playBellWebAudio` which returns an Observable for the completed ringing of a bell sound. I want to be able to trigger bell rings by calling `.next()` on a Subject, and I want the rings to queue up, so I'd use `concatMap`.

But then how should I a) cancel the current bell singly and b) cancel all pending bell rings?

I think I can get single cancelation to work like this, but I wish it could read cleaner:

```
const ringer = new Subject<void>();
const cancels = new Subject<void>();
ringer
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() => {
      return defer(playBellWebAudio).pipe(
        // Allow single-cancelation
        takeUntil(cancels)
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

ringer.next() // Add ring to the queue
cancels.next() // Cancel the current ring playing
```

But, I can't get queue-cancelation to work in raw RxJS like I can with `@rxfx/effect`.

The RxFx code, for comparison is:

```
import { createEffect } from '@rxfx/effect'
const bellRinger = createQueueingEffect(playBellWebAudio);

bellRinger.cancelCurrent(); // cancels one
bellRinger.cancelCurrentAndQueued(); // also empties the queue
```

Can anybody show idiomatic RxJS for both single and multiple cancelation?

- [CodeSandbox of RxJS version](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rxjs-bell-effect-wkg9d3)
- [CodeSandbox of  (fully-cancelable reference version)](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/rxfx-queued-cancelable-bell-jt89t9?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A11%2C19)

BTW This is similar to the unanswered [Canceling the inner Observable in concatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896948/is-there-any-way-to-cancel-rxjss-concatmaps-inner-observable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your current code is pretty good and that you just need to handle the entire queue cancelling, which can be done in several ways, here are some examples:

```js
const ringer = new Subject<void>();
const cancels = new Subject<void>();
const restartEntireQueue = new Subject<void>();

restartEntireQueue
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      ringer.pipe(
        concatMap(() =>
          defer(playBellWebAudio).pipe(
            // Allow single-cancelation
            takeUntil(cancels)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe();

ringer.next(); // Add ring to the queue
cancels.next(); // Cancel the current ring playing
```

or also

```js
ringer
  .pipe(
    concatMap(() =>
      defer(playBellWebAudio).pipe(
        // Allow single-cancelation
        takeUntil(cancels)
      )
    ),
    takeUntil(restartEntireQueue),
    repeat()
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Best / only answer today, so accepted for the purpose of showing the RxJS code as I asked. 

Now, that said, is there any reason someone would prefer to read that vs the RxFx code I posted above, with fewer operators, less indentation, etc?

Comment: I don't know anything about that library. But looking at the source code on github, it looks like it all goes down to this function: https://github.com/deanrad/rxfx/blob/main/service/src/createService.ts#L61-L377 which without digging too much into it... Seems a bit overkill for what we're trying to achieve here. But it does the work so I guess it's up to you whether you want to embed another lib or not, i guess it comes down to how much are you going to take advantage of it